# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, do I include file wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At first I wanna say: "Sorry me, my english is not well"

Look at my situation. I try to use an import at my page (http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/).

But not all new browsers can support that possibility.

And I do that trick to including files:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function supportsImports() {
        return 'import' in document.createElement('link');
    }

    if (supportsImports()) {
        // Read more below 1
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.href = 'include.html';
        link.rel = 'import';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    } else {
        // Read more below 2
        console.log('Use other libraries/require systems to load files.');
        includingList = ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js' ,'contextMenuBehaviour.js' ];
        for (var file in includingList){
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = includingList[file];
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    }
</script>
```

1 : (IF true) Here I wanna get that string in head of my page

```
<link href="include.html" rel="import">
```

And here all is correct. And all is working.
Browsers: Chrome, Opera

2 : (IF false) Here I wanna get that's strings in head of my page

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="contextMenuBehaviour.js"></script>
```

Browsers: Maxthon, FireFox.
And in this browsers I had got that strings in the Head.
But everytime and wherever I had try to use Jquery and I get an error.

I can't understand why Jquery doesn't work after including?

Maybe in that browsers I can't include in that way.
Then how can I do include this files?

Comment: Do you see the new script elements hen you debug your page with firebug or similars? Also, have your tried to specify that the script.type = 'text/javascript' ?

Comment: @satchcoder I don't installed other debuger. Only integrated tools.

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="contextMenuBehaviour.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` ? Okay, I tried that, but result same.